# Error when adding checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, phaser-framework

My `create` function is as follows:

```
create: function() {    
   var checkbox1 = game.add.checkbox( 10, 10, { text: 'labeltext', style: { fill: '#ffffff' } }, 'texture' );

   checkbox1.events.onInputUp.add( function( elm, pointer ){
      alert( checkbox1.state );
   }, this );
}
```

However, this is returning the following error:

> Phaser.Cache.getImage: Key "texture" not found in Cache

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using the [Checkbox addon for Phaser](http://www.phaser-lernen.de/phaser-addons/checkbox/1).

According to the documentation, the fourth parameter in the `game.add.checkbox` function is a string that should be a key corresponding to a stored texture in the Phaser Cache.

You've specified the string `'texture'` as the value for this parameter.

The error message you're seeing means that you've either not loaded an asset with `texture` as its key, or you loaded it but then cleared it from cache somehow.

If it's the former (most likely), then you need to make sure you're loading it before you attempt to use it as the texture for this checkbox:

```
game.load.image('texture', 'path to texture');
```